# Bootstrap Carousel Image Resizing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap for a website I started working on, and I added a carousel, but it keeps re-sizing my images to be aligned to the left and a lot smaller but I can't figure out why. This is what it looks like right now

```
<body>

<div id="homePageCarousel" class = "carousel slide">

<ol class = "carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#homePageCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#homePageCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#homePageCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>

<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active">
  <img src="Images/paper1.jpg" alt="paper1" class="img-responsive">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>StudentShare</h3>
    <p>Click the picture to learn more!</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <img src="Images/sunset.jpg" alt="sunset" class="img-responsive">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>Another Ad</h3>
    <p>Description of this Ad</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <img src="Images/paper2.jpg" alt="paper2" class="img-responsive">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>Another Ad</h3>
    <p>Description of this Ad</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<a class="carousel-control right" href="#homePageCarousel" data-slide="next">
<span class="icon-next"></span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#homePageCarousel" data-slide="prev">
<span class="icon-prev"></span>
</a>

</div>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">                      </script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you asking for something like this [jsBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/boqayabo/1/)

I changed `max-width: 100%` to `width:100%` to use all width

Comment: That does fix it, but a friend already helped me by just forcing the image to center. Thanks!